# ReactJS: How to recognize if a browser tab has been closed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

While being on a website built with ReactJS (Javascript + HTML (JSX)), if the tab that the website was on gets closed/deleted by the user, I would like to trigger a function.

Is it possible to recognize if the browser tab that the website was viewed on gets closed or not? And if so, how can I go about doing so in Javascript?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible

But, you can trigger a confirmation to close the tab

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }
    return 'Sure?';
}
```

Comment: onbeforeunload is a bit problematic. First off, if you try and block me without really good reason, I'll be upset. Secondly, it cannot start (or guarantee an) async action completes.

Comment: @user2864740 That's true. This UX has both pros and cons. For content aware applications like stackoverflow uses it to ensure the user doesn't lose their contents(when they are answering or asking questions). In these cases I see them helpful.

Comment: @PraneshRavi How is it them that some websites are able to trigger logging out of user when a tab gets closed?

Comment: That is by `session`. Read about `user session`

Comment: @PraneshRavi Is there one in particular for ReactJS you can refer me to? But when the browser closes the tab, isn't the application somehow recognizing it and deleting the session?

Comment: Yes, the session id will be stored in the session storage. When the tab gets closed the session storage will be cleared. So, when the user reloads the page the server will initiate a new session.